# GCDWebServer how to add custom parameter to the request(GET/POST)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gcdwebserver

```
[_webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"GET" path:@"/111" requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class] asyncProcessBlock:^(GCDWebServerRequest *request, GCDWebServerCompletionBlock completionBlock) {

    GCDWebServerDataResponse *response = [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithJSONObject:@{
                                                                                        @"123":@"123"
                                                                                        }];
    completionBlock(response);
}];
```

I am an iOS developer with ObjC, found GCDWebServer very useful.but I want to simulate for setting my custom request(like json dictionary @{@"name":@"jim",@"age":@"20"}) ? 
I do not know how, can some one help me ,thx! (support GET/POST)

Comment: You need to make your question more precise: what exactly are you trying to achieve? It's not not needed to link to the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your custom parameters on the URI after the pathname like this using ?param=1 with param the name of the value and 1 is the value so the full URI would be for example :

http://192.168.105.18:8080/setLockBackLight?param=1

to get the parameter value using the GET method for example,simply access
to the GCDWebServerRequest values like this :

NSArray *values = request.query.allValues;